# How to delete break points?

Tags: visual-studio

Somehow in visual studio I made a breakpoint. I want to get rid of it but I don't know how. It's the yellow arrow. I'm using visual studio 2013 community edition. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: check the views/windows in the menus there should be a break points list there then you can delete them

Comment: Are you really using Visual Studio to write *java*?

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeing a yellow arrow... That is the current run point when you are debugging. To get rid of it... Just stop debugging.